# How do I copy mail into another mailbox using imap_mail_copy?

Tags: php, email, imap

The usually comprehensive PHP manual is missing any complete examples of using the [imap_mail_copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-copy.php) function.  Specifically I'm looking for an example of what to supply in the **$msglist** variable to the function.  The documentation recommends reading [RFC2060](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html) which I cannot comprehend.

I want to ultimately write a function to copy a message into the a Sent folder upon sending an email.

Can someone provide an example of using the **imap_mail_copy** function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just copying one message, use the same `msg_number` you'd use in an `imap_headerinfo` call (etc.).

If you're copying more than one message, join the message numbers with commas (but no spaces).  E.g. "`3,4,7,9`".

[The lousy documentation for `imap_mail_copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-copy.php) says:

> msglist is a range not just message numbers (as described in » RFC2060).

What this means is that if you want to copy a bunch of messages with consecutive message numbers (e.g. `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`) you can just use a "range" and encode it as "`1:7`".  But, honestly, it's usually much easier to just have a comma-separated list.

It's described a lot better in [the `imap_fetch_overview` page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php):

> A message sequence description. You can enumerate desired messages with the X,Y syntax, or retrieve all messages within an interval with the X:Y syntax

Comment: Ah so the very obvious use of imap_msgno (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-msgno.php) I think I'll oly be coping one message at any time.  I'll try it.

Comment: If you've got a UID, you can hand it directly to `imap_mail_copy`.  Just make sure to pass `CP_UID` as the `options` parameter.